# How to get list of folders and subfolders from full path in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to get a list of all subfolders here, I need to find all excels for each district folder in Maharashtra state.

```
{CREATE TABLE ALLFILENAMES(WHICHPATH VARCHAR(255),WHICHFILE varchar(255))

--some variables
declare @filename varchar(255),
        @path     varchar(255),
        @sql      varchar(8000),
        @cmd      varchar(1000)

--SET @path = 'E:\Maharashtra\Ahamadnagar\'
SET @path = 'E:\Ahamadnagar\'
SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.csv /b'
INSERT INTO  ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
UPDATE ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null}
```

Comment: create function to the list , explained well in here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b0807d1b-fa79-4d1f-9b96-7c462df0cecd/need-to-get-folder-and-subfolders-list?forum=transactsql

Comment: Another method explained [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/everyday-sql/2012/12/31/how-to-use-xp_dirtree-to-list-all-files-in-a-folder-part-2/)